# Incoordination (sentence-initial equivalents of "and")

Tags: list-of-languages, conjunctions, coordination, imperative

In Italian, the conjunction corresponding to "and" can be used in imperative constructions for emphatic purposes, as in:

> E smettila! ('And stop!', i.e: 'Do stop!').

This is probably the outcome of a diachronic process whereby the first clause preceded by the conjunction has come to be ellipsed: (Do this) and stop!

Are there any other languages in which the counterparts of "and" are used in incoordinated contexts (i.e. sentence-initially), be it in this function or in different ones?

Comment: You see this occasionally in English too. "And don't come back!"

Comment: Thanks! Would you utter this sentence in isolation without a previous imperative such as: "go away/leave me in peace"?